# Excel formula = Sum 2 columns, find the max of the sum and get data from another column using the max row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

Imagine i have 3 columns

```
Date   Data1  Data2
1st      4      5
2nd      7      8
```

What i want to do is sum Data1 and Data2 together, and find the date on which the maximum occurs.

Currently i use `=Max (INDEX (B2:B3 + C2:C3))` to get the maximum value of the sum but i cant think of how to get the row on which  the max occurs so as to get the date

Thought of using index match to do it but am at a loss atm

I do not find if u use VBA too cow im gonna code the formula into VBA later on. Using excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

Please see below image and formula to achieve your result (if I understood it correctly)

[image]

Formula for cell E2:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(D1:D4),D1:D4,0),1)
```

For VBA Solution:

```
Sub LargeFind()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow, currentLarge, largeRow As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Your workbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Your sheet name

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

currentLarge = 0
largeRow = 0
For i = 2 To lastRow
    ' B & C are the columns where your data is
    If ws.Range("B" & i).Value + ws.Range("C" & i).Value > currentLarge Then
        currentLarge = ws.Range("B" & i).Value + ws.Range("C" & i).Value
        largeRow = i
    End If
Next

ws.Range("D2").Value = ws.Range("A" & largeRow).Value '<-- "D2" is your output cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi dubison yep. However i want to achieve E2 without creating column D. This seems difficult cos MATCH requires a lookup array

Comment: maybe you may achieve that with an array formula however I do not have enough knowledge about array formulas.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately i have only done very basic arrays and im at a loss at how to do it here too.

Comment: is it ok for you to use VBA?

Comment: Yes it is, vba is very ideal. Currently i code it into vba using Range ("E2") = (Formula) so people who cant understand vba can understand it. But using pure vba is ideal too given the complexity of this issue.

Comment: Hi Dub your vba code works! Much appreciated! I have since converted it into a formula so as to use it more iteratively

Comment: great, maybe if you can post your formula solution here as an answer maybe someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Sure, problem is, i will need to use this function in another worksheet later on, i should be able to call it though, altho any ideas on how to do it will be appreciated. I added the function as a suggested edit to ur answe